# How to Silence the read command

Tags: bash

The read command is useful when reading data from the user . I am trying to read a number from 1-5 from the user. How can I make it so the input of the user does not show up in the log

Comment: In general "man COMMAND" often gives you many information about a  command and its options, usage and so on. Sometimes "COMMAND --help" gives you a brief overview. Sometimes even faster than SE. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the bash built-in version of `read`, you can use the `-s` option. From `help read`:

```
-s      do not echo input coming from a terminal
```